# Updating rows in parse with javascript

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm trying to update a specific field in a row in my parse table when clicking a button. The button gets the object id, and it sets an alert with the object id just to make sure we get the right objectId, but the updating line doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

```
button.onclick = function () {

   var MyItems = Parse.Object.extend("MyItems");
   var query = new Parse.Query(MyItems);
   query.equalTo("objectId", this.id);
   query.first({
     success: function(object) {

     alert(object.get('objectId'));

     object.set("status", "ok");
     object.save();


  },
  error: function(error) {
  alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
  }
 });
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work? What evidence are you using?

Comment: the update lines don't work,

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Comment: well, the status field does not change

Comment: How and when are you checking for the change?

Comment: In parse dashboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! 
ACl was not set to write.
Changed it to public write and everything works out fine.